# Confusing behavior of the Python logging module in a multiprocessing context

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, multiprocessing

So I am trying to use `logging` in a `multiprocessing` context. Say I want to have each process write its own log file. Here is my setup:

```
# worker.py
import logging
import os

def worker( x ) :
    """
    Write the value of x in the log file
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger( __name__ )
    pid = os.getpid() # get the process id
    handler = logging.FileHandler( str(pid) + ".log" )  
    logger.addHandler( handler )
    logger.info( "pid={pid}, x={x}".format( **locals() ) )
```

This is my `main`:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
import worker

# logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel( logging.INFO )

# handler
handler = logging.FileHandler( 'main.log' )
logger.addHandler( handler )

#
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    pool = mp.Pool( processes=2 )
    pool.map( worker.worker, range(5) )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

And now the output log files. This is `main.log`:

```
pid=1985, x=0
pid=1985, x=2
pid=1986, x=1
pid=1985, x=3
pid=1986, x=4
```

I think this output is normal: the two child processes propagate events to the root parent. So it does **not** correspond to the [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) scenario (does it?). But now here is the first child process log file:

```
pid=1985, x=0
pid=1985, x=2
pid=1985, x=2
pid=1985, x=3
pid=1985, x=3
pid=1985, x=3
```

And this is the second child log file:

```
pid=1986, x=1
pid=1986, x=4
pid=1986, x=4
```

It looks like each child process writes the log once for the first input, twice for the second, three times for the third, etc. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because every time you enter `worker`, you're getting a reference to the same `logger` object, and then add a new `FileHandler` to it. So if `worker` is called three times, its `logger` ends up having three `FileHandlers`, which all happen to write to the same file. You should use the `initializer` keyword argument to set up the logger in each `Pool` process once at startup:

```
def init( ) :
    logger = logging.getLogger( __name__ )
    pid = os.getpid() # get the process id
    handler = logging.FileHandler( str(pid) + ".log" )  
    logger.addHandler( handler )
```

Then start the pool like this

```
 p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2, initializer=init)
```

Then worker can just grab the `logger` object and use it without adding a `FileHandler` to it.